# How do use display block?

Tags: css, html, block

How do I "activate" the second test in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

hiddentext1 {
    display: none;
}
something1:hover + hiddentext1 {
    display: block;
}


hiddentext2 {
    display: none;
}
something2:hover + hiddentext2 {
    display: block;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<something1>First test</something1>
<hiddentext1>Text from first test.</hiddentext1><br />
<br />
<something2>Second test</something2>

<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <td><hiddentext2>Text from second test.</hiddentext2></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I need to setup some ID for the table...? I am not sure what else to write or ask...?

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain what's going on. What's not happening that you believe should be happening.

Answer (score 2):

Well your second `hiddentext2` isn't a sibling to `something2`, so you can't use the adjacent selector like that. The table, however, *does* follow it, so use the table to scope out `hiddentext2`:

```
something2:hover + table hiddentext2 {
    display: block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/ME5mX/)

Hopefully these oddly named tags are just for your testing purposes. You should use valid and meaninful tags, not ones that you've made up.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to make the text in the "hiddentext2" box appear when hovering over "something2" then the following code will do this. I have also changed the non standard tag names into divs with classes:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    .hiddentext1 {
        display: none;
    }

    .something1:hover + .hiddentext1 {
        display: block;
    }


    .hiddentext2 {
        display: none;
    }

    .something2:hover + table .hiddentext2 {
        display: block;
    }

    </style>


    </head>

    <body>


    <div class="something1">First test</div>
    <div class="hiddentext1">Text from first test.</div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="something2">Second test</div>

    <table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tr>
            <td><div class="hiddentext2">Text from second test.</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

You can view this at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cosmicwheels/4tHt2/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to be triggered so the second test appears. But let's presume you have a button for that, you need to do it in javascript, something like:

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $("#button_trigger").click(function(){
              $("#second_answer").css("display", "block");

              return false;
          });
     });
</script>
```

And your html for the second part would be something like:

```
<a href="#">Answer number 2</a>
<div id="second_answer">
      //your table and so on
</div>
```

So when the user clicks that button the second question will appear.